# Can you left-justify or bold the table/figure caption for Kable in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

I am using RMarkdown to write reproducible reports, however, I am looking for guidance on how to change the justification on table/figure captions when using Kable?

Also, can you **bold** or *italicize* the **Table 1:** component of the caption?

```
knitr::kable(head(iris), 'latex', caption = 'Title of table',
             booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kableExtra::kable_as_image()
```

This code will produce a generally nice looking table. However, I want to left-justify the title and bold the text "Table 1:" which automatically precedes my table caption.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are aiming for PDF output, the table caption formatting will be done by LaTeX.  You can modify what it does using the `caption` package.  See https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption.

Comment: @user2554330 Can this LaTeX package be used inside the Rmd file to change the way LaTeX formats the caption when rendering a PDF?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the LaTeX `captions` package to customize your captions.  For example, this document

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[justification=raggedright,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE) 
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(head(iris), caption = 'Title of table',
             booktabs = TRUE)
```
````

produces this table output:

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively, if you really want this in a screenshot file, use

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
kable(head(iris), format="latex", caption = 'Title of table',
             booktabs = TRUE) %>% 
  as_image(file="~/temp/table.png", 
      latex_header_includes="\\usepackage[justification=raggedright,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}")
```

Comment: Just came across this as solution to an issue I was having, many thanks.